# python linting not working with eglot

Tags: python, lsp, eglot, python-lsp-server

```
System:
Mac OS 12.5
Emacs 28.1 from homebrew
Python 3.9.13 using a virtual env
python-lsp-server
```

For some reason my linting, with error highlighting is not working with Python using eglot.

In the screenshot below (`hello_broken.cpp`) you can see that linting is working in C++ mode which is using clangd.

The middle pane shows that linting is not working for Python (`hello_broken.py`).  There should clearly be the same kind of error as in the Cpp file.

However, you can see that eglot is giving me the function intellisense for `add.py` as shown in the message buffer at the bottom.  Also, the go to definition functionality of eglot is also working.

Why isn't the linting working?  I don't really even know how to dig into this, but any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although I have `pylint` installed `python-lsp-server` was looking for `pyflakes`.  At this moment, I don't know if I can configure the server to use `pylint` instead.